# Sqlite3 - foreign key mismatch on BLOB

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I am using foreign keys, unfortunately in the case bellow I am not able to solve the mismatch... What am I missing? The tebles are created by:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `devices` (
    `guid`  BLOB NOT NULL,
    `device_name`   TEXT NOT NULL,
    `class` INTEGER NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `device_states` (
    `guid_d`    BLOB NOT NULL,
    `id_d`  TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    `tp`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `state` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `note`  TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    `status`    INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(`guid_d`,`tp`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`guid_d`) REFERENCES devices ( `guid` ) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_ds_tp ON device_states(`tp`);

INSERT OR IGNORE INTO `devices` VALUES (x'438D6E77DC3946A4819617ADBA18ADB2','guid_door', 1);
```

The select bellow works as expected:

```
SELECT * FROM `devices` WHERE guid = x'438D6E77DC3946A4819617ADBA18ADB2';
```

> 1 Rows returned from: SELECT * FROM `devices` WHERE guid = x'438D6E77DC3946A4819617ADBA18ADB2'; (took 1ms)

However, when I try to insert data to *devices* table, I get the error...

```
INSERT INTO device_states (guid_d, id_d, tp, state, note, status) 
VALUES (x'438D6E77DC3946A4819617ADBA18ADB2', "D", 132456, 1, "door open", 2);
```

> foreign key mismatch - "device_states" referencing "devices": INSERT
>   INTO device_states (guid_d, id_d, tp, state, note, status) VALUES
>   (x'438D6E77DC3946A4819617ADBA18ADB2', "D", 132456, 1, "door open", 2);

Does anybody see the issue??? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) says:

> Usually, the parent key of a foreign key constraint is the primary key of the parent table. If they are not the primary key, then the parent key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or have a UNIQUE index.

There is no such constraint on `guid`.